# Implementing a composable predicate type with embedded error messages / user feedback

Tags: swift, swiftui, predicate

I have a "Swifty" version of NSPredicate that is based on a simple closure. This makes it composable but I'd like to find a way of implementing error messages to give the user feedback in the UI.

The problem arises when I attempt to compose two predicates with a logical AND - with my current implementation (which kept the predicate very simple), I can't find a meaningful way of generating an error message from the component predicates. An obvious solution would be to add a computed property to the predicate that will re-evaluate the predicate and return an error (if applicable) but that seems very inefficient.

I started to look into exposing error messages via a Combine Publisher but this got out of control quickly and seems unnecessarily complex. I've concluded that I now can't see the wood for the trees now and could do with a bit of a steer. Code base follows...

Predicate:

```
public struct Predicate<Target> {
    // MARK: Public roperties
    var matches: (Target) -> Bool
    var error: String

    // MARK: Init
    init(_ matcher: @escaping (Target) -> Bool, error: String = "") {
        self.matches = matcher
        self.error = error
    }

    // MARK: Factory methods
    static func required<LosslessStringComparabke: Collection>() -> Predicate<LosslessStringComparabke> {
        .init( { !$0.isEmpty }, error: "Required field")
    }

    static func characterCountMoreThan<LosslessStringComparable: Collection>(count: Int) -> Predicate<LosslessStringComparable> {
        .init({ $0.count >= count }, error: "Length must be at least \(count) characters")
    }

    static func characterCountLessThan<LosslessStringComparable: Collection>(count: Int) -> Predicate<LosslessStringComparable> {
        .init( { $0.count <= count }, error: "Length must be less than \(count) characters")
    }

    static func characterCountWithin<LosslessStringComparable: Collection>(range: Range<Int>) -> Predicate<LosslessStringComparable> {
        .init({ ($0.count >= range.lowerBound) && ($0.count <= range.upperBound) }, error: "Length must be between \(range.lowerBound) and \(range.upperBound) characters")
    }
}


// MARK: Overloads

// e.g. let uncompletedItems = list.items(matching: \.isCompleted == false)
func ==<T, V: Equatable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate { $0[keyPath: lhs] == rhs }
}

// r.g. let uncompletedItems = list.items(matching: !\.isCompleted)
prefix func !<T>(rhs: KeyPath<T, Bool>) -> Predicate<T> {
    rhs == false
}


func ><T, V: Comparable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate { $0[keyPath: lhs] > rhs }
}


func <<T, V: Comparable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    //    Predicate { $0[keyPath: lhs] < rhs }
    Predicate({ $0[keyPath: lhs] < rhs }, error: "\(rhs) must be less than \(lhs)")
}


func &&<T>(lhs: Predicate<T>, rhs: Predicate<T>) -> Predicate<T> {
    return Predicate({ lhs.matches($0) && rhs.matches($0) }, error: "PLACEHOLDER: One predicate failed")
}

func ||<T>(lhs: Predicate<T>, rhs: Predicate<T>) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate({ lhs.matches($0) || rhs.matches($0) }, error: "PLACEHOLDER: Both predicates failed")
}
```

Validator (consumes predicates):

```
public enum ValidationError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    case generic(String)

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .generic(let error): return error
        }
    }
}

public struct Validator<ValueType> {
    private var predicate: Predicate<ValueType>

    func validate(_ value: ValueType) -> Result<ValueType, ValidationError> {
        switch predicate.matches(value) {
        case true:
            return .success(value)
        case false:
            return .failure(.generic(predicate.error)) // TODO: placeholder
        }
    }

    init(predicate: Predicate<ValueType>) {
        self.predicate = predicate
    }
}
```

Validator struct is utilised by a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
public class ValidateAndPublishOnMain<ValueType> where ValueType: LosslessStringConvertible { // Type constraint specifically for SwiftUI text controls
   @Published private var value: ValueType

    private var validator: Validator<ValueType>

    public var wrappedValue: ValueType {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    // need to also force validation to execute when the textfield loses focus
    public var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Result<ValueType, ValidationError>, Never> {
        return $value
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { value in
                self.validator.validate(value)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    public init(wrappedValue initialValue: ValueType, predicate: Predicate<ValueType>) {
        self.value = initialValue
        self.validator = Validator(predicate: predicate)
    }
}
```

...and finally, use of the property wrapper in SwiftUI (and associated view model)

```
public class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ValidateAndPublishOnMain(predicate: .required() && .characterCountLessThan(count: 5))
    var validatedData = "" {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }

    var errorMessage: String = ""
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        setupBindings()
    }

    private func setupBindings() {
        $validatedData
            .map { value in
                switch value {
                case .success: return ""
                case .failure(let error): return error.description
                }
        }
        .assign(to: \.errorMessage, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var error = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Label")
                TextField("Data here", text: $viewModel.validatedData)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            }.padding()

            Text("Result: \(viewModel.validatedData)")
            Text("Errors: \(viewModel.errorMessage)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.objectWillChange.send() // ensures UI shows requirements immediately
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "meaningful" error message? Would a message such as `"\(lhs.error) or \(rhs.error)"` be considered meaningful? If not, then you must generate the error _as you evaluate_ the predicate. It can't be a hardcoded constant anymore. So my second question is, are you open to entirely different designs? For example, one change I would make is `matches` should return a `Result<(), ValidationError>`.

Comment: Thanks for questions. I worded the question poorly - I should have said “unambiguous” so the “... or ...” isn’t ideal and I need to be aware of screen real estate. The difficulties I’ve encountered did make me suspect I’m using the eronf approach; I just wanted to get an outside view to make sure I wasn’t missing something obvious. I’m certainly open to an alternate strategy and suspect that the Validator type may actually be redundant.

Comment: Actually, why is `||` ambiguous? If it fails, both predicate must have failed, so a message of "... and ..." is not ambiguous. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why you have ambiguities is that the error messages are "set in stone" too early. For an `&&` operation, you don't know the error message until the expression has been evaluated.

Therefore, you should not store an `error` property. Instead, only have the error message outputted when `matches` returns, i.e. as its return value. Of course, you'd also need to handle the success state where there is no error message.

Swift provides many ways to model this - you can return a `String?` representing the error message, or a `Result<(), ValidationError>`, or even a `Result<Target, ValidationError>`.

And as long as you made the error message the return value of `matches` (whichever type you chose), you shouldn't have this ambiguity problem.

Here, I've done it with `Result<(), ValidationError>`. Honestly, the code itself I quite straightforward:

```
public struct ValidationError: Error {
    let message: String
}

public struct Predicate<Target> {
    var matches: (Target) -> Result<(), ValidationError>

    // MARK: Factory methods
    static func required<T: Collection>() -> Predicate<T> {
        .init { !$0.isEmpty ? .success(()) : .failure(ValidationError(message: "Required field")) }
    }

    static func characterCountMoreThan<T: StringProtocol>(count: Int) -> Predicate<T> {
        .init { $0.count > count ? .success(()) : .failure(ValidationError(message: "Length must be more than \(count) characters")) }
    }

    static func characterCountLessThan<T: StringProtocol>(count: Int) -> Predicate<T> {
        .init { $0.count < count ? .success(()) : .failure(ValidationError(message: "Length must be less than \(count) characters")) }
    }

    static func characterCountWithin<T: StringProtocol>(range: Range<Int>) -> Predicate<T> {
        .init {
            ($0.count >= range.lowerBound) && ($0.count <= range.upperBound) ?
                .success(()) :
                .failure(ValidationError(message: "Length must be between \(range.lowerBound) and \(range.upperBound) characters")) }
    }
}

func ==<T, V: Equatable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate {
        $0[keyPath: lhs] == rhs ?
            .success(()) :
            .failure(ValidationError(message: "Must equal \(rhs)"))
    }
}

// r.g. let uncompletedItems = list.items(matching: !\.isCompleted)
prefix func !<T>(rhs: KeyPath<T, Bool>) -> Predicate<T> {
    rhs == false
}

func ><T, V: Comparable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate {
        $0[keyPath: lhs] > rhs ?
            .success(()) :
        .failure(ValidationError(message: "Must be greater than \(rhs)"))
    }
}

func <<T, V: Comparable>(lhs: KeyPath<T, V>, rhs: V) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate {
        $0[keyPath: lhs] < rhs ?
            .success(()) :
        .failure(ValidationError(message: "Must be less than \(rhs)"))
    }
}


func ||<T>(lhs: Predicate<T>, rhs: Predicate<T>) -> Predicate<T> {
    // short-circuiting version, needs a nested switch
//    Predicate {
//        target in
//        switch lhs.matches(target) {
//        case .success:
//            return .success(())
//        case .failure(let leftError):
//            switch rhs.matches(target) {
//            case .success:
//                return .success(())
//            case .failure(let rightError):
//                return .failure(ValidationError(message: "\(leftError.message) AND \(rightError.message)"))
//            }
//        }
//    }

    // without a nested switch, not short-circuiting
    Predicate {
        target in
        switch (lhs.matches(target), rhs.matches(target)) {
        case (.success, .success), (.success, .failure), (.failure, .success):
            return .success(())
        case (.failure(let leftError), .failure(let rightError)):
            return .failure(ValidationError(message: "\(leftError.message) AND \(rightError.message)"))
        }
    }
}

func &&<T>(lhs: Predicate<T>, rhs: Predicate<T>) -> Predicate<T> {
    Predicate {
        target in
        switch (lhs.matches(target), rhs.matches(target)) {
        case (.success, .success):
            return .success(())
        case (.success, let rightFail):
            return rightFail
        case (let leftFail, .success):
            return leftFail
        case (.failure(let leftError), .failure(let rightError)):
            return .failure(ValidationError(message: "\(leftError.message) AND \(rightError.message)"))
        }
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
public class ValidateAndPublishOnMain<ValueType> where ValueType: LosslessStringConvertible { // Type constraint specifically for SwiftUI text controls
   @Published private var value: ValueType

    private var validator: Predicate<ValueType>

    public var wrappedValue: ValueType {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    // need to also force validation to execute when the textfield loses focus
    public var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Result<ValueType, ValidationError>, Never> {
        return $value
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { value in
                // mapped the Result' Success type
                self.validator.matches(value).map { _ in value }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    public init(wrappedValue initialValue: ValueType, predicate: Predicate<ValueType>) {
        self.value = initialValue
        self.validator = predicate
    }
}
```

Note that I've changed your `ValidationError` to a struct rather than an enum. You could make this conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` if you don't like the verbosity of `ValidationError(message: ...)`.

Another thing that you might want to consider is the messages for predicates involving key paths. Key paths don't have a human-readable string representation, so you can't have "isCompleted must equal false" as the message for `\.isCompleted == false`.

Comment: Thank you for the steer. Now I've seen the code, I'm trying not to feel too stupid! ;-)  As you've pointed out, the problem related to premature assignment of the error property but I just couldn't see a way around it. I kept banging away at it as I thought it was actually to be quite a simple problem and just ended up boxing myself into a corner! I agree the struct is a better data structure than the enum (it seems more lightweight) but I'll probably go with ExpressibleByStringLiteral as you suggest...